# Critical values of exponential function

Tags: differential-geometry, exponential-function, geodesic, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a globally hyperbolic spacetime, $S \subset M$ Cauchy hypersurface with unit normal vector field $n$, $\Sigma \subset S$ compact 2-dim. submanifold with unit normal vector field $\nu$.

I have a defined function $\exp: (- \epsilon, \epsilon) \times \sigma \rightarrow M$ defined via $\exp(r,p)=c_p(r)$ where $c_p$ is the null geodesic with $c^{'}_p(0)=n_p+\nu_p$.

Not a general definition for a critical value for a differentiable map between smooth manifolds $f:M \rightarrow N$ is $f(p)$ where $(df)_p$ is not surjective.

So a critical value of $\exp$ is a point $\exp(r,p)$, s.t. $(d \exp)_{(r,p)}$ is not surjective.

My problem is that I don't exactly know what $(d \exp)_{(r,p)}$ is supposed to be..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your question rightly, you are looking for critical points on a geodesic.

Recall that we have geodesics defined by means of an exponential function. The remainder of this paragraph is a throwback to our Calculus 101 (or whichever the name was) days: exponential functions are of the form $\exp(f(x))$, and thus, where differentiable, their derivative shall be $f'(x) \exp(f(x))$. Observe that $\exp$ is globally positive, so critical points shall only present where $f'(x)=0$, i.e. wherever the argument $f(x)$ has a critical point. End of the throwback.

Back in our problem, singularities (critical points) will present if and only if they are *provided by the spacetime*.

Let's elaborate on that. First, a remark on geometry: $(d \exp)_{(r,p)}$ will fail to be surjective if and only if $c'_p(r) = 0$. Why? Recall that, in general, for any smooth function $f:M\to N$ we have that its differential will be a linear map $f:TM\to TN$ between the corresponding tangent bundles. This is just jargon for *for each $p\in M$ there is a linear transformation $df:T_p M\to T_{f(p)} N$ such that vectors tangent to $M$ at $p$ are sent to vectors tangent to $N$ at $f(p)$*. In this case, the geodesic $c_p(\cdot):(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to \gamma;\quad r\mapsto c_p(r)$ shall be singular wherever its differential is not surjective, i.e. whenever its tangent vector is $0$.

Now recall that, by means of $c_p(r)$ we have a rule that associates points in our space with geodesic paths, and that these geodesic paths will evolve according to the metric $g$ we have on $M$. Wherever the metric presents a singularity, so will $c_p(r)$, which shall be the null vector there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm still not sure if I understand why it $(d \exp)_{(r,p)}$ is surjective $\Leftrightarrow$ $c_p^{'}(r) \neq 0$. My thoughts on this: $d \exp (r,p):(- \epsilon, \epsilon) \times T_p\Sigma \rightarrow T_{exp(r,p)} M, (t,v) \mapsto (f \mapsto v(f(c_p(r))=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n v^i \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(c_p(r)) \cdot c_p^{'}(r))$ So $(d \exp(r,p))(v)=0 \Leftrightarrow v=0$  if $c^{'}_p(r)\neq 0$ so $(d exp)_{(r,p)}$ injective if and only if $c^{'}_p(r)\neq 0$ and since these are finite-dim. spaces the surjectivity argument follows, is that correct?

Comment: Also I don't understand what you mean by "these geodesic paths will evolve..."

Comment: Don't regard the exponential as a function on $\Sigma$, but as a rule that  associates to each point $p\in \Sigma$ a path $c_p(\cdot)$.

Comment: By 'will evolve' I mean that, as $r$ grows, ...

Comment: But if it's not a function, how is then the differential of $\exp$ defined?

Comment: But you have that $\exp_p(r) = c_p(r)$ is a function. This is something you can differentiate as a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\Sigma$.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, but if I write it out in the way I did it is similar to what I wrote right?

Comment: Yes, notation shouldn't worry you too much as long as you are clear what it stands for.

Comment: Ok, thank you again !